# error: expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"; error: expected ';' before "__attribute__"

Tags: c

I am compiling a C program on Solaris 10 for x86, the code is:

```
#if defined (__GNUC_MINOR__)&&2093<=(__GNUC__*1000+__GNUC_MINOR__) __attribute__ ((__unused__))
#endif
```

When I compile this, I get the error message:

```
error: expected primary-expression before "__attribute__"; error: expected ';' before "__attribute__"
```

What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That needs to be spread over 3 lines:

```
#if defined (__GNUC_MINOR__)&&2093<=(__GNUC__*1000+__GNUC_MINOR__)
 __attribute__ ((__unused__))
#endif
```

This tests whether you're using a suitable version of GCC (based on the GCC version number), and if so, generates an `unused` attribute annotation for whatever preceded these lines.

As written, the expression was simply invalid; the C preprocessor on Solaris probably saw:

```
#if defined(__GNUC_MINOR__) && 2093 <= (0*1000+0) 0 ((0))
```

which is not a valid expression at all.